# How to determine trend and uncertainty from dataset

Tags: statistics, linear-regression, data-analysis

I have a dataset with the cumulative ice mass change of the Greenland Ice Sheet with units Gt (Gigatonnes) and its uncertainty (error estimate).

```
yr=[2003.038356 2003.117808 2003.208219 2003.287671 2003.358904 2003.539726 2003.619178 2003.709589 2003.789041 2003.879452 2003.958904 2004.019126 2004.128415 2004.20765  2004.289617 2004.379781 2004.459016 2004.538251 2004.628415 2004.70765  2004.789617 2004.879781 2004.959016];
mc=[94.91467285 -106.5794067    -39.28155518    -0.194824219    -4.950927734    -193.9120483    -397.7717896    -389.0446777    -302.5618896    -271.7980347    -341.026062 -325.5195313    -319.352417 -287.8536377    -210.249939 -255.0377808    -234.324707 -405.8927002    -533.7174072    -574.6280518    -641.2060547    -519.1424561    -509.010376];
mc_error=[281.3519897   178.404007  159.776001  135.2619934 186.845993  115.685997  127.3939972 122.6439972 101.6019974 111.5830002 110.0019989 243.348999  123.1790009 93.52189636 107.526001  162.6710052 194.0769958 233.6569977 876.4349976 418.4100037 698.5339966 162.121994  129.7559967];
```

I found a paper which used the slope of a linear regression to derive mean annual mass changes from the same type of data (but from a different source, so they may differ) with units in Gt yr-1:

[image]

When I apply a linear regression to my data, I get a slope (or mean mass change) of -276.11 Gt yr-1. But I am wondering how to determine (1) the acceleration (in Gt yr-2) and (2) the uncertainty/error from these data as done in this paper (-276.11 +/- what?). Can someone help me?

Thanks!